# inserting en equation inside a cell and super/subscript

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office-2016

I'm using OS X office 2016 and i want to insert the equation **inside** the cell. I'm planning on pulling it out as data to Word later (using exceltoword!).
also i can't figure out how to use subscript or superscript in this version. no combination of keys with +/= works out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the text whose format you want to change in the Formula Bar, and choose `Format Cells...` to change the font, etc. Despite the name, the change will apply only to the selected text. For example:

[image: demonstrate text formatting of part of a cell's text]

Comment: @arielhasidim, I don't know what you mean by, "I'm using OS X office 2016 and i want to insert the equation inside the cell." Everything goes in cells in Excel. If you clarify, maybe I can help with the rest of your question.

Comment: i found this explanation before but for some reason when i click ok in the "format cell" dialog all the changes disappear. i think its because of the OS X office 2016.... also i want yo use fraction lines.

Comment: @arielhasidim, did you select the text you want to format with the mouse in the Formula Bar first? Or try pressing F2, and you should be able to select it in the cell itself? I am using Windows 7, so I guess it could be different...